# I can not go to a specific directory after using htaccess and mod_rewrite? RewriteCond for directories does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I want setup an administration panel in my project in **cp** directory. But I can not go to it after using htaccess and mod_rewrite. Below is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ ./index.php?p=$1 [NC,N]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ ./index.php?p=$1 [NC,F]
```

I get 403 forbidden access when the URL is **http://localhost/project/cp**

What do I have to do ?

Comment: 403 forbidden usually means you've forgotten to put a default document into the directory (index.html, index.php, etc...) and directory browsing is disabled.

Comment: @MarcB I know it, but here it means that previous rules could not be matched and the process receives to the end and F flag runs

Comment: Yes, but if `.../cp` is a directory, it'll be explicitly EXCLUDED from rewriting by the `!-d` rule, which means the next two rewriterules won't be considered at all.

Comment: You'll need to repeat the two RewriteCond line in front of the second RewriteRule.

Comment: @MarcB the 403 is because he is using the `[F]` flag.

Comment: @Gerben your solution did not work for me. By the way, the RewriteCond does not need to repeat actually. The problem I have is this. It seems they do not work exactly

Comment: @MarcB you are right. This is my problem. RewriteCond does not work I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a useful answer for my question and it worked for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```